# Update query with value from specific select query (nested statement)

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, i want to update data from table wdetail which its value taken from another table (jdes) using below statement:

```
UPDATE wdetail SET cdate = (SELECT datetime FROM jdes WHERE woid = '1' AND statusw = 'COMPLETED') WHERE wid = '1';
```

But somehow these statement didnt provide any change. Need advice. Thanks.
P/S: woid and wid are synchronize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE wdetail w
JOIN jdes j on j.woid = w.wid
SET w.cdate = j.datetime 
WHERE w.wid = '1'
AND j.statusw = 'COMPLETED'
```

Comment: Recommended solution! Thanks